# Using templates without "controllerAs" prefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you'll see the code, you'll notice that I set `template` property as `{{$.aaa}}`. Is there a way to avoid usage of `controllerAs` prefix before variable and use the template in form `{{aaa}}`?

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    class Controller {
        constructor(){
            this.aaa = 111;
        }

        doSomething(){
            alert(this.aaa)
        }
    }

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.directive('any', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: Controller,
            controllerAs: '$',
            template: '{{$.aaa}}'
        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: in that case 'aaa' should be a property of the $scope, not of the Controller. Be aware that the controllerAs syntax is the preferred way nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Inject $scope into your controller constructor, then attach your property to scope.

```
class Controller {
    static $inject = ["$scope"];

    constructor($scope) {
        $scope.aaa = "value";
    }
}
```

And :

```
app.directive('any', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: Controller,
        template: '{{aaa}}'
    };
});
```